# How to get cron job to use ssh-agent for current user

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn

I'm trying to persist an ssh tunnel connection with Remote port forwarding to access a machine behind a home router, using a cron job, as shown in this blog: https://juliansimioni.com/blog/howto-access-a-linux-machine-behind-a-home-router-with-ssh-tunnels/

Problem is my vpn has an identity file with password to connect to ssh. I can only connect at terminal typing in password each time. Adding the password via ssh-agent , ssh-add didnt work for cron job. How to get cron job to use the ssh-agent for current user?

Comment: For an automated process, I'd be inclined create a key without a passphrase, and configure the server to limit what command(s) the key can be used for.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
ssh-agent > ~/.ssh/.ssh-agentrc
ssh-add
<enter your passcode when prompted>
```

Then in your script:

```
. ~/.ssh/.ssh-agentrc
```

Hey presto - your key is available in your script's environment!